# Gcloud list all projects including ones pending deletion?

Tags: gcloud

I know I can:

```
gcloud projects list
```

However, this does not show projects pending deletion. How can list those as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```bash
gcloud projects list --filter='lifecycleState:*'
```

Comment: Grande Daz! <3 I think your filter is a bit too generic as it works for all LCSs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just filter:

```bash
gcloud projects list --filter='lifecycleState:DELETE_REQUESTED'  [--format yaml|json]

PROJECT_ID                  NAME                 PROJECT_NUMBER
my-project-deleteme-298812  My Project DELETEME  1033904603578
```

Note this is also in the help function of `gcloud projects list  --help`